# PostgreSQL запрос на разность

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос, как мне сделать запрос на разность.
[Разность] Получить список учителей, которые не имеют нагрузки в
текущем полугодии (нет в расписании).
Пробовал так:

```
select id_teacher from teacher

EXCEPT

select id_teacher from discipline_teacher;
```

Это сделано тупо по айди. А как сделать, по нормальному,чтобы я мог еще показать Имя, фамилию учителя.

Comment: not exists или left join с проверкой на null в части where

Comment: select teacher.name,teacher.last_name from teacher
left join discipline_teacher on discipline_teacher.id_teacher = teacher.id_teacher
left join raspisanue on discipline_teacher.id_discteacher = raspisanue.id_discteacher
where discipline_teacher.id_discteacher is null

Comment: Вот так получилось, вроде бы результат правильно выдает. Это можно считать разностью ? Вот вопрос

Answer (score 1):

> как сделать, по нормальному,чтобы я мог еще показать Имя, фамилию учителя.

Добавить их в каждый подзапрос:

```
  select id_teacher, name, last_name 
  from teacher
EXCEPT
  select t.id_teacher, t.name, t.last_name
  from discipline_teacher dt, teacher t
  where dt.id_teacher=t.id_teacher;
```

Или добавить их к начальному запросу:

```
select t.id_teacher, t.name, t.last_name
from teacher t, (  select id_teacher from teacher
                 EXCEPT
                   select id_teacher from discipline_teacher) dt
where dt.id_teacher=t.id_teacher;
```

Ну и LEFT JOIN никто не отменял.